distribute javafx application that uses .class files and and a run script (classical way to run java program)
i want to learn how do i can to distribute my javafx application without using jlink or jpackage, just with the .class files and the libraries. so i'm facing a problem when trying:
i'm using windows. I have created a javafx application for desktop. i want to distribute that application but i'm not using module system or jpackage, i want to package the application myself (.class files). but i'm getting a javafx error JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application i did it:

created a directory to my application, its name is "spar". with this structure. i'll explain the structure.


spar
       java = this directory contains a minimal java runtime generated using the command "jlink --output java" the client dont have java installed and cant install it.
       classes = this directory is a direct copy of the maven directory "target/classes". it contains the .class files generated during the compilation of my source code.
       libs = it contains the dependencies of the my application, it was obtained using the Apache Maven Dependency Plugin, a maven plugin which generates a directory with all dependencies of your program. so there have a lot of .jar files which are the dependencies of my apllication. among them there a lot of javafx libraries.
       bin = from my knowledgement javafx runtime requires native libraries (dlls) so this directory contains those dlls required to run javafx. they were obtained from javafx sdk from the gluon website (https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).


inside the "spar" directory i'm trying to run my application with the command: ./java/bin/java.exe --class-path "classes;libs/*" -Djava.library.path=bin spar.Main but i'm geting the error JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.


the run parameter -Djava.library.path is a cli parameter which load native libraries. from my knowledgement it can be used with a directory.

so i dont know what is wrong, in my head i have did all things that are necessary. the native libs and the javafx libraries. i dont understand why do i still get that error.
so always there a person that says "why do you dont use the module system or a fatJar (executable jar)...?" R: i'm giving up fatJar because i already had a lot of problems with them sorry but not, i prefer a run script at least for desktop. and second i dont want to use modules, i dont like the module system, and i dont want to be forced to use modules or i would feel as it were a "gun pointing to my head". and i dont know nothing about jpackage what is it another gun? should i crouch to it point to my head too?
already have questions about how to distribute a javafx application but none them asks about using the classic way to run java code using .class files and a script file. all them use jpackage, jlink, ide etc. cause it i believe it is not a duplicate.
i already have tried to create the java image (jlink) with the javafx modules (jmods) and i got the same thing.
i expect that my program open. it works fine in intellij. or at least learn how javafx requeriments/runtime works and why do i'm getting that error.

That error, in practice, can mean only one thing: The main class is a subtype of Application but the javafx.graphics module was not found in the boot module layer. The technically correct solution is to launch your application in such a way that the JavaFX modules are loaded from the module-path. If you don't want to do that, then a current workaround is to separate the main class and application class, then have the main class simply launch JavaFX.

https://fxapps.blogspot.com/2020/11/creating-fat-jars-for-javafx.html

@slaw yeah i have tested that, if you have a main class which dont extends Application but it call the class that extends it works. i have created a new main class called TrueMain and it just calls the Main class and it ran. but just calling the Main class gives that error. i never would solve this problem myself. i consider this thing a bug and a unstability of the language/javafx. sad. but big thanks for the answer. and it have solved my problem. but is a shame for javafx.

It's a deliberate design choice. The part of the JDK that allows a JavaFX application class to omit the main method explicitly checks for the javafx.graphics module when the main class is a subtype of Application. If the module is not found then the code chooses to abort the launch and emit the error you're seeing. JavaFX technically does not support being loaded from the class-path. That said, I understand the frustration, especially since JPMS adoption doesn't seem to have spread as much as the JDK developers probably hoped. Luckily, the workaround I mentioned continues to work.

If you're curious, this behavior is implemented here. Note "java.launcher.cls.error3" is the resource bundle key for "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" and the equivalent for other languages.

There are JDK/JRE distributions from Liberica (Full JDK/JRE) Zulu (JDK/JRE FX) that include JavaFX.  You can use those.  They put JavaFX modules on the standard module path and make them available to non-modular apps, the same as the rest of the standard JDK modules.  You don't need any command line switches to use them, you can write javac HelloFX.java and java HelloFX to compile and run a simple JavaFX app from the command line.

If you're already distributing a "minimal Java runtime generated using jlink", why not generate that runtime with the JavaFX modules included? Then you are in the equivalent scenario to using a prepackaged JDK/JRE with JavaFX included, as described in @jewelsea's comment (but with added control over exactly which modules you include).

just an addition, the command jlink --output java creates a minimal java image but it can only run simple things, like a "hello world", so is required to add the modules to run more complexes things. as my program would require a lot of modules so now i'm using the full sdk, instead trying to create a lower version/image of the sdk (jlink). so the sdk size (graal) is > 600M. but as i'll ship it in a pendrive i can afford it.

You could create a fat jar, like it  is done in this Git repo: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

You can use --add-modules to control which modules are included in the run-time image created by jlink. Also see --bind-services and --limit-modules. Be cautious about the former though, as you can end up with significantly more modules from the JDK than you need. The latter can help with that, but I often find it easier to just explicitly list the needed modules with --add-modules.
